# Issues rendering data correctly using flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: html, jinja2

**Background:** Having issues querying data from flask sqlalchemy database correctly. In the html template, I'm using the html5 datalist tag in a for loop to render each field listed under column1 of my table. Table is classList and column1 if field1.

**Issue:** Currently the data renders in a cluster, meaning the whole entire column will render for every field in the dropdown list. I'm trying to get it to render each cell only, under column 1. I tried trailing the results variable with .first() but I get an "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'field1'" error. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

**views.py**

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    classList = db.Table('classList', db.metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=db.engine)
    results = [i.field1 for i in db.session.query(classList)]
    return render_template('index.html', results=results)
```

**html template**

```
{% block content %}
    <input type="text" list="classlist" Placeholder="Search list..">
    <datalist id="classlist">
    {% for i in results %}
        <option>{{ results }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </datalist>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: How about `<option>{{ i }}</option>` ?

Comment: Oh my goodness. Of course, it's always something small. Thank you so much! I didn't even consider that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kruspe provided the solution. Change results in the  tag to i.

```
<option>{{ i }}</option>
```